# Caps Lock / Double Caps Lock to switch a keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm seeking a new way to toggle between keyboard layouts on my Ubuntu system. Specifically, I'd like to achieve the following:

- A single press of the Caps Lock key should switch to the English layout.
- A double press of the Caps Lock key should revert to the national layout.

Currently, with the help of gnome-tweaks, I've set it up so that pressing Caps Lock switches between layouts. While this method is practical, I find it sometimes confusing as I have to determine which layout is currently active.

Are there any solutions or scripts that can help me achieve this more nuanced behavior?

Here's a brief overview of my system:

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2
- Kernel: 5.19.0-50-generic
- Desktop: GNOME Shell 42.5

Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!